# Как подсчитать сумму в массиве объектов?

Tags: javascript

Как подсчитать сумму coinBet где RedAndBlack num=2

```
let arr=[
{
    uid: 1,
    infoUser:  {
    ontime: '1',
    room: null,
    lastTime: 0
},
RedAndBlack: { num: 2, coinBet: 3 }
},
{
    uid: 2,
    infoUser:  {
        ontime: '1',
        room: null,
        lastTime: 0
    },
    RedAndBlack: { num: 2, coinBet: 3 }
    },
    {
    uid: 4,
    infoUser:  {
        ontime: '1',
        room: null,
        lastTime: 0
       },
         RedAndBlack: { num: 1, coinBet: 3 }
       }
     ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let arr = [{
    uid: 1,
    infoUser: {
      ontime: '1',
      room: null,
      lastTime: 0
    },
    RedAndBlack: {
      num: 2,
      coinBet: 3
    }
  },
  {
    uid: 2,
    infoUser: {
      ontime: '1',
      room: null,
      lastTime: 0
    },
    RedAndBlack: {
      num: 2,
      coinBet: 3
    }
  },
  {
    uid: 4,
    infoUser: {
      ontime: '1',
      room: null,
      lastTime: 0
    },
    RedAndBlack: {
      num: 1,
      coinBet: 3
    }
  }
];

console.log(arr.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + (curr.RedAndBlack.num === 2 && curr.RedAndBlack.coinBet), 0))
```